# Install Build Essential Fails on Ubuntu 24.04 Fresh install due to libc6-dev dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install --yes build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out on Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed       
            Depends: libtirpc-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnsl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Not sure why this is happening.  I am new to Linux and this is a brand new install.  I was just trying to install a few packages I need to use my other programs and build essential keeps failing.  I saw online it may have something to do with a newer version of the libc6-dev, but I have tried all the different methods people had online and none of it is working.  Hopefully someone here can help out.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to do an update first:

```
sudo apt update
```

After try again:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, however I completely rebuilt my VM and started over, and I started with sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade and it worked, so thank you!